# Trouble with PHP code, trying to echo some html and open a file and print

Tags: php, html

I'm very new to PHP and I am trying to use some php code to echo some buttons, and then when the buttons press it opens a file and writes a number in that file. This code doesn't seem to be working and I cant figure out why. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
    echo '
        <form method="post">
        <input type="Submit" name="button1" value="Led1 On" />
        </form><br>';

    echo '
        <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="button2" value="Led1 OFF" />
        </form><br>';

    echo '
        <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="button3" value="Led2 On" />
        </form><br>';

    echo '
        <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="button4" value="Led2 OFF" />
        </form><br>';

    if (isset($_POST["button1"])){
        echo "LED 1 is ON";
        $myFile = 'data.txt';
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
        fwrite($fh, "1*");
        fclose($fh);
    }

    if (isset($_POST["button2"])){
        echo "LED 1 is OFF";
        $myFile = 'data.txt';
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
        fwrite($fh, "2*");
        fclose($fh);
    }

    if (isset($_POST["button3"])){
        echo "LED 2 is ON";
        $myFile = 'data.txt';
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
        fwrite($fh, "3*");
        fclose($fh);
    }

    if (isset($_POST["button4"])){
        echo "LED 2 is OFF";
        $myFile = 'data.txt';
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
        fwrite($fh, "4*");
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

Edit: Seems finding out everyone else got it working lead me to believe it was user error. And it was. Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you receive any warnings/errors? is error reporting on?

Comment: So when you do `print_r $_POST`, what does it show? :)

Comment: It is working fine for me. What exactly is not working?

Comment: and you can take fopen() and fclose before and after the "if" conditions instead of opening and closinh in each "if"

Comment: Are you saving it to your local computer or to a web server? If it's your local computer, do you have a web server application running? (Apache, IIS, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more DRY way to write this code:

```
$myFile = 'data.txt';   

if (is_writable($myFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');

    if (isset($_POST["button1"])){
        echo "LED 1 is ON";
        $string = "1*";
    }

    if (isset($_POST["button2"])){
        echo "LED 1 is OFF";
        $string = "2*";
    }

    if (isset($_POST["button3"])){
        echo "LED 2 is ON";
        $string = "3*";
    }

    if (isset($_POST["button4"])){
        echo "LED 2 is OFF";
        $string = "4*";
    }

    fwrite($fh, $string);
    fclose($fh);

} else {
    echo "The file $myFile is not writable.";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `is_writable` call : permissions-related problems are therefore much easier to detect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run php inside a webserver like Microsoft IIS or Apache HTTP.

Try looking at http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Comment: I don't think the OP's HTTP request actually failed ; his server setup is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Create data.txt and set permissions 777

Comment: How do you know it's Linux based environment?

Comment: code is working (with data.txt file with permissions 777) , what do you mean "Linux based environment"?

Comment: And there it is, the basic Windows user's answer. 777 permissions is **evil**, it grants everything, to everyone, why would anyone do that for no reason ? Even for testing purposes, this doesn't solve the problem : proper permissions would still be needed afterwards. The OP needs to make sure the web server (www-data) has write permission on the file, and execution permission on all parent directories. This doesn't apply to Windows-based web servers (WAMP).

Comment: it's txt file, what can happen if set permissions 777 for him?

Comment: What if this file determines an application's behaviour ? Imagine an application that reads this file, and when it sees "delete all" in it, just erases the web root directory (or anything else www-data can act on). Anyone could add "delete all" to this file with 777 permissions, and boom. This is **not** an actual solution, it barely serves testing purposes (a comment would therefore be more appropriate). Plus : .txt files do not need their execution bits set except in specific cases.

Comment: Sorry, but do you see code above? He can delete all ? If yes, so do it here http://coding.kz/stack/data.txt file with 777 permissions (it's my domain).

Comment: This is **one** piece of code, and **one** application, as much as my comment was **one** example of situation. It would be very common for a file to be shared between several applications ; the context should not make the answer more acceptable. This answer does not give any indication on the actual problem. Also note that the permissions thing is already covered in comments, and serves the question's improvement instead (about your link : the file itself isn't the risk ; its permissions are)